# Browser URL changing even after using Server.Transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.transfer

I am using Asp.net 4.0. I do a server.transfer from page 1 to page 2. The URL remains page 1. Now I click a link on page 2 and that will transfer me to page 3. So the URL should remain page 1. Instead the browser now shows the URL of page 2. Is that the expected behaviour?

I was actually trying to hide the Page URL.

Can anybody help me on this.

I know there is duplicate question on stack overflow but it doesn't have any convincing answer
and question is 4 years old too. Please Help me with this or suggest better way to achieve this

Code :

**On page1**

```
Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");

}
```

**On Page2**

```
Btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

server.Transfer("Page3.aspx");

}
```

Comment: how do you transfer between page 2 and page 3?

Comment: What is the nature of the "link" on page 2 that you click on? Is it just an `<a>` on the page, or is it some form of server-side control?

Comment: @Zaki Using server.transfer

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Its server side control and server.transfer is used to transfer to Other page

Comment: Well, that's the reason the URL is changing then. The browser is trying to move to another page and it has to do that by submitting a postback request to page 2 so that the server-side control can work. So the browser has to know that it's hitting page 2.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I believe that when you use server.transfer then no data is posted to browser

Comment: Yes, but the `Server.Transfer` between pages 1 and 2 is well in the past and irrelevant at the point when you click the link on page 2 - the browser has to send a request somewhere, and that somewhere is page 2.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there any other way to hide url.

Comment: The only way to *keep* the URL referring to page 1 is to stay on page 1 - and thus have to absorb all of the functionality and controls from the other pages into it, and deal with the complexity of showing and hiding controls at appropriate times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remember** "Server.Transfer does not change the URL in the address bar"

Check this site you will get clear idea about Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJVjRUHXYbE&index=54&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXQS_p1i-HLIftB9Y7Vnxlo

When  Using Server.Transfer

For ex:

Page1.aspx, Page2.aspx

In page1.aspx assume code in button click like this

Server.Transfer("~/page2.aspx");

Then you will redirect to page2.aspx but url shown in address bar is same i.e; page1.aspx eventhough you are in page2.aspx.

when you use Response.Redirect it will show page2.aspx when you redirected to page2.aspx

***Coming To your Question:***

This is an expected behavior.

You asking Url changes if you use Server.Transfer in second time

If you run page1.aspx for first time then it shows

```
Address Bar : `http://localhost:1234/WebSite3/Page1.aspx`

Action Name : "page1.aspx"//see pagesource
```

if you click button in page1.aspx it will shows page2.aspx but with same url like:

```
Address Bar : `http://localhost:1234/WebSite3/Page1.aspx`  but different

Action Name="page2.aspx"//see pagesource
```

if you click button in page2.aspx it will shows page3.aspx but with different url like:

```
Address Bar : `http://localhost:1234/WebSite3/Page2.aspx`  but different 

Action Name="page3.aspx"//see pagesource
```

Here you find different url why because eventhough your url is page1.aspx but your request comes from page2.aspx see page source.So for this reason the url changes from page1.aspx to page2.aspx.

Comment: This not my problem i think you miss understood. Please read this again

Comment: @ArjunSharma see my updated answer i will send some code in a little bit of time.otherwise check video you will get clear idea

Comment: That what my concern is That browser URL is changing even after using server.Transer which should not happen

Answer (score 2):

Arjun,
You page2.aspx is making server calls after it is rendered. It is that server call that is causing the name change. Server.Transfer wont change your name.

Check if this problem happens in IE, if not, you may be missing certain images that referred by the page. Else watch the server calls using fiddler